# Replace the TD tag

Tags: javascript

I want to replace the `<td>` tag.

My code looks like this:

```
var divele = document.createElement("div");
divele.innerHTML = "<td><p>content</p></td>";

var tdele = document.getElementByd("tdid");
tdele.parentNode.replaceChild(divele.firstChild,tdele);
```

The `tdid` is replaced with the `<p>` tag content only not with the `<td>`.

When I assign the `<td>` content to the `innerHTML` of the `<div>`, the `<td>` is replaced from that content (as per the block level element).

How do I replace the `<td>` with the new `<td>` content using `innerHTML`?

Comment: A `td` element can only be a child of a `tr` element. You will experience bizarre and unpredictable behaviour across different browsers if you try to put it in a `div`.See the HTML Tables spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html

Answer (score 1):

```
var td = document.getElementById('tdid');
td.innerHTML = "<p>content</p>";
```

simply put the content into the td directly.

replacing td cells can cause weird behaviour and will give you unexpected results if it works at all.

Comment: In fact, there are certain cases where doing this kind of replacement can actually cause memory exceptions in IE.